# ionic 2 ionicViewLoad() not firing

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am creating a mock ionic project, where I am using Google maps, the data is fetched from the remote server and the view is rendered only after the data is received so when I call the loadMap() method in ngOnInit() lifecycle hook It throws an error but it doesn't, when I use ionViewLoad() method.However,this method doesn't gets fired at all.
The component code snippet,

```js
ionViewLoaded(){
      this.loadMap();
      console.log('map called');
  }

loadMap() {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.0168445, 76.95583209999995);
    let mapOptions: Object = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    console.log(this.post.loc[0].pin.lat);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

API have changed. In Ionic 2 RC.1 it is changed to "`ionViewDidLoad`".
For more information, look [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: It throws an error ` ionViewDidEnter error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

Comment: That's means yours code is getting called. this.mapelement is undefined that's why you are getting this error. Make sure it's properly Initialized.